# Why does boost::multi_array's ConstMultiArrayConcept have a NumDims template argument?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-multi-array, c++-concepts

I wrote an `operator<<` specialization that handles `boost::multi_array`, and used `ConstMultiArrayConcept` so that it would work on both the outer array and the sub-arrays. I'm wondering, though, why the `multi_array` concepts have a `std::size_t NumDims` template argument, since that can be simply extracted from the `multi_array`. The only use of `NumDims` in `ConstMultiArrayConcept` is as a recursion depth arg for `idgen_helper`, which tests slicing.

For reference, here's the header for `multi_array` concepts:
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/boost/multi_array/concept_checks.hpp

And here's my overloaded `operator<<`

```
template <typename CharT, typename Traits, typename MultiArrayT>
BOOST_CONCEPT_REQUIRES(
                       ((boost::multi_array_concepts::ConstMultiArrayConcept<MultiArrayT, MultiArrayT::dimensionality>)),
                       (std::basic_ostream<CharT, Traits>&)) // return type
operator <<( std::basic_ostream<CharT, Traits>& os, MultiArrayT const& ary )
{
    typename std::basic_ostream<CharT, Traits>::sentry opfx( os );

    if ( opfx ) {
        boost::multi_array_types::size_type const* sizes = ary.shape();
        // using Mathematica array notation
        os << "{";
        for ( int i = 0; i < sizes[0]; ++i ) {
            if ( i > 0 ) os << ", ";
            // verbose just to keep the types apparent
            typedef typename MultiArrayT::const_reference subType;
            subType item = ary[i];
            os << item;
        }
        os << "}\n";
    }
    return os;
}
```

This specialization works, but I must be missing something in my understanding. Any clues will be appreciated.

Comment: In short, because most of the time you check whether the array type has a specific dimension.

Comment: Your specific requirement simply check if the type is a const array, mainly ignoring the dimensionality in that line.

Answer (score 2):

Declaration of concept template class:

```
template <typename Array, std::size_t NumDims>  struct ConstMultiArrayConcept
{
...
};
```

See how `ConstMultiArrayConcept` is actually used in Boost code:

```
 template <typename T, std::size_t NumDims>
 class multi_array_ref {
   ...
   // Assignment from other ConstMultiArray types.
   template <typename ConstMultiArray>
   multi_array_ref& operator=(const ConstMultiArray& other)
   {
      function_requires< 
         detail::multi_array::
         ConstMultiArrayConcept<ConstMultiArray,NumDims> >();
      ...
```

The same code in `multi_array_view& operator=()` and `sub_array& operator=()` that take other `ConstMultiArray` type.

Looks like `NumDims` **is not** dimension number of passed array type `Array`, it's dimension number of outer array type that checks assignment compatibility with given other array type. So it could not be deduced from `Array` template parameter.

Answer (score 0):

`ConstMultiArrayConcept<MA, D>` and `MutableMultiArrayConcept<MA, D>` check if `MA` fulfills the concept of a (mutable) array of dimension `D`.

For example, these concept checks success:

```
{
    using MA = boost::multi_array<int, 1>;

    BOOST_CONCEPT_ASSERT((boost::multi_array_concepts::ConstMultiArrayConcept<MA, 1>));
    BOOST_CONCEPT_ASSERT((boost::multi_array_concepts::MutableMultiArrayConcept<MA, 1>));
}
```

since `MA` has dimension 1.

And same with

```
{
    using MA = boost::multi_array<int, 2>;

    BOOST_CONCEPT_ASSERT((boost::multi_array_concepts::ConstMultiArrayConcept<MA, 2>));
    BOOST_CONCEPT_ASSERT((boost::multi_array_concepts::MutableMultiArrayConcept<MA, 2>));
}
```

However this one fails because there is a dimensionality mismatch:

```
{
    using BMA = boost::multi_array<int, 2>;

    BOOST_CONCEPT_ASSERT((boost::multi_array_concepts::ConstMultiArrayConcept<MA, 1>));
    BOOST_CONCEPT_ASSERT((boost::multi_array_concepts::MutableMultiArrayConcept<MA, 1>));
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/98TefGa9e

With an error message:

```
/usr/include/boost/multi_array/concept_checks.hpp: In instantiation of ‘static void boost::multi_array_concepts::detail::idgen_helper<0>::call(Array&, const IdxGen&, Call_Type) [with Array = boost::multi_array<int, 2>; IdxGen = boost::detail::multi_array::index_gen<1, 1>; Call_Type = long int]’:
/usr/include/boost/multi_array/concept_checks.hpp:71:44:   required from ‘void boost::multi_array_concepts::ConstMultiArrayConcept<Array, NumDims>::constraints() [with Array = boost::multi_array<int, 2>; long unsigned int NumDims = 1]’
/usr/include/boost/concept/detail/has_constraints.hpp:32:62:   required by substitution of ‘template<class Model> boost::concepts::detail::yes boost::concepts::detail::has_constraints_(Model*, boost::concepts::detail::wrap_constraints<Model, (& Model::constraints)>*) [with Model = boost::multi_array_concepts::ConstMultiArrayConcept<boost::multi_array<int, 2>, 1>]’
/usr/include/boost/concept/detail/has_constraints.hpp:42:5:   required from ‘const bool boost::concepts::not_satisfied<boost::multi_array_concepts::ConstMultiArrayConcept<boost::multi_array<int, 2>, 1> >::value’
/usr/include/boost/concept/detail/has_constraints.hpp:45:51:   required from ‘struct boost::concepts::not_satisfied<boost::multi_array_concepts::ConstMultiArrayConcept<boost::multi_array<int, 2>, 1> >’
/usr/include/boost/concept/detail/general.hpp:51:8:   required from ‘struct boost::concepts::requirement_<void (*)(boost::multi_array_concepts::ConstMultiArrayConcept<boost::multi_array<int, 2>, 1>)>’
/home/user/boost-multi/test/boost_array_concept.cpp:19:2:   required from here
/usr/include/boost/multi_array/concept_checks.hpp:51:8: error: no match for ‘operator[]’ (operand types are ‘boost::multi_array<int, 2>’ and ‘const boost::detail::multi_array::index_gen<1, 1>’)
   51 |       a[ idgen ];
      |       ~^
In file included from /usr/include/boost/multi_array.hpp:34,
                 from /home/user/boost-multi/test/boost_array_concept.cpp:8:
/usr/include/boost/multi_array/multi_array_ref.hpp:530:3: note: candidate: ‘template<int NDims> typename boost::multi_array_ref<T, NumDims>::array_view<NDims>::type boost::multi_array_ref<T, NumDims>::operator[](const boost::detail::multi_array::index_gen<NumDims, NDims>&) [with int NDims = NDims; T = int; long unsigned int NumDims = 2]’
  530 |   operator[](const detail::multi_array::
```